# List comprehension with 2 variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, python-2.x

Having following list

```
base_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If I want to separate it into 2 lists by criteria `x > 5` in one line I will do sonething like this

```
 list_1 = [num for num in base_list if num < 5]
 list2 = [num for num in base_list if num > 5]
```

I'm wondering if it possible to make it one line?

Something like this

```
list1, list2 = [num for num in base_list if num < 5 and_here_else_part_for_second_list]
```

Comment: `list_1 = [num for num in base_list if num < 5]; list2 = [num for num in base_list if num > 5]` -- Good enough for "one line"? :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible to fit it in one line (and even one *statement*)...

```
list_1, list2 = [num for num in base_list if num < 5], [num for num in base_list if num > 5]
```

But you probably don't want to do that :-) (there aren't any advantages that I can see)...

There are other ways that you could fit it into 1 comprehension, but none of them are particularly "clean".  What you have is about as good as it gets I'm afraid.